# How to include jsp file with images in another folder

Tags: jsp

I have a header.jsp file with a navigation bar that includes an image in the root folder. I then have the contacts.jsp in a subfolder. I want to include the header.jsp in contacts.jsp but the bootstrap and image does not show.

I have tried using <%@include file="../header.jsp" %> and <%@include file="/header.jsp" %> with both showing just the HTML.

header.jsp in the root folder:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/mainstyles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><img src="resources/images/icon.png" height="50" alt="Logo" style="display: inline"></li>
                            <li><a href="contacts.jsp">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p id="welcomeMessage" class="pull-right">Welcome <a href="profile.jsp"><strong id="userName"></strong></a> | <a href="logout.jsp">logout</a></p>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

and then contacts.jsp in the contacts subfolder in the root folder:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <%@include file="/header.jsp" %>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the header.jsp file everything shows like it should. When I run the contacts.jsp file I see the HTML, but without any bootstrap added and the image does not show.

The structure of the project is as follows:

- Web Pages

  - META-INF
  - WEB-INF
  - resources

    - bootstrap

      - css

        - bootstrap.min.css
      - js

        - bootstrap.min.js
    - css
    - images

      - icon.png
  - contacts

    - contacts.jsp
  - header.jsp

Comment: For clarification: you want to include the posted file header.jsp into the posted contacts.jsp? If so, then is no wonder, because the browser will reciveive a misspelled html syntax.

Comment: Yes, the header.jsp has a nav-bar with an image, and is saved in the root folder. I have various other jsp files in different folders and I want them all to display the nav-bar with the image. It works when everything is in the same folder, but I need it in different folders because the files just become to difficult to manage.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP page is a method for creating a fast servlet, and a servlet is a component for creating an HTML page or a component for work with a protocol for the server.

So the evolution of standard JSP imported the method for include another o more page inside the page JSP main but the your code not work because of the `<%@include file="/header.jsp" %>` is a static inclusion and in your cases, you had included the HTML page inside another HTML page and this is wrong because the inclusion result is a unique HTML page.

So an example of the code work is

Your page header.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/mainstyles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><img src="resources/images/icon.png" height="50" alt="Logo" style="display: inline"></li>
                            <li><a href="contacts.jsp">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p id="welcomeMessage" class="pull-right">Welcome <a href="profile.jsp"><strong id="userName"></strong></a> | <a href="logout.jsp">logout</a></p>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Your page contact.jsp:

```
   <%@include file="/header.jsp" %>
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

so when the browser has the response to the server have a correct HTML

Inside the your browsare you can see this result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/mainstyles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"         rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><img src="resources/images/icon.png" height="50" alt="Logo" style="display: inline"></li>
                            <li><a href="contacts.jsp">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p id="welcomeMessage" class="pull-right">Welcome <a href="profile.jsp"><strong id="userName"></strong></a> | <a href="logout.jsp">logout</a></p>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I have clean the code, for creating a correct HTML, As you also suggest in the comment

Comment: I forgot in the example to include header.jsp, thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you. I understand the html in html in html and have rectified my code so that the header.jsp only has the nav-bar with image and my other pages, in this case contacts.jsp, has the html tag with the include. However it is still not showing the image in contacts.jsp

Comment: I think the img path depends to the relative path of the server, the your build dir respect the standard javaee? can you post the your structure of the project?